# Install Package changed my web.config dependent Assembly

Tags: asp.net, nuget-package

After install a Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization on my project. It change some versions on my web.config.

I would like know if it's a bug ?

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.BaseLibrary" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Blog" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Cms.Shell.UI" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Configuration" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

File changed by nuget instalation:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.BaseLibrary" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.530.0" newVersion="6.0.530.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Blog" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Cms.Shell.UI" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.2.375.0-6.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="6.1.379.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer.Configuration" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.530.0" newVersion="6.0.530.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EPiServer" publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.530.0" newVersion="6.0.530.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way some frameworks update to preserve back compatibility. Other ones release conversion tools (i.e DevExpress). Just do backups and check if your project compiles fine.